# Include CoreData model from another framework into the main app

Tags: swift, core-data

Since I use other extensions in my app, I want to define my `CoreData` and all the associated logic in a separate framework, which is then accessed by the main app, as well as all extensions.

When I want to access this from my main app I get the error message:

> No NSEntityDescriptions in any model claim the NSManagedObject
> subclass 'FrameworkName.EntityName' so +entity is confused.  Have you
> loaded your NSManagedObjectModel yet ?

As the error message says, probably the Main app does not know the `CoreData` model, because it is not loaded there.

In other SO posts [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088367/how-to-use-core-datas-managedobjectmodel-inside-a-framework), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130420/casting-fails-for-core-data-codegen-subclasses-implemented-in-both-app-and-frame)] it is written that you have to make changes in `AppDelegate`. I added the following code hoping that this will load the `CoreData`, unfortunately it does not. Can anyone help.

```
@main struct WebListsApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            FolderView()
        }
    } }

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModelName")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unable to load persistent stores: \(error)")
            }
        }
        return container
    }()
    
    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        let frameworkBundleIdentifier = "frameworkIdentifier"
        let customKitBundle = Bundle(identifier: frameworkBundleIdentifier)!
        let modelURL = customKitBundle.url(forResource: "DataModelName", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
    }()
}
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the `build folder` & the `derived data`?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the derived data and cleaned thee build folder. I also checkt the names of my DataModel and selected 'Current Product Module' as the Module in the DataModel for the Entities. These are the typical issues that I could think of, based on some other SO-posts.

Comment: What code are you executing when you’re getting the error?

Comment: I am running the main app (WebLists - code above) on a simulator. 
In the FolderView i just have a button, which calls a method from a class inside the framework with the CoreData. This method simply creates and adds a new Entity to CoreData. 

The Error above occurs, when I click the button in the FolderView in the simulator.

When I run code using the CoreDataModel within the framework I do not get any errors.